# How to set log4j.configuration file system property in unix

Tags: unix, log4j2

I am new to unix, I want to set the log4j2.xml in unix machine.Can any one tell me how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in anywhere on the CLASSPATH and it will be picked up.